# How do i send automated emails from my server script

Tags: email, smtp

I am writing a small phone app that requires a mail to be sent to a specified email address from the apps back-end server.

I see there are lots of scripts to achieve this in vb and c# etc but they all seem to require SMTP servers which im not familiar with.

Can anyone advise on how i should get a simple email sent from a server script with no expensive off the shelf packages?

Comment: I mean, you could simply use python and imaplib to send an email with what ever you would like in it.

Comment: How do i do this -do i not need a mail server or something?

Comment: No, you can just use gmail or anything really. Look up an example with imaplib and gmail.

Comment: Did you figure it out? If not, I can provide full examples.

Comment: No, just started looking at stuff on  imaplib and gmail. examples would be brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to send an Email using python (this is from a program that checks emails and sends out emails)

```
import smtplib, imaplib
global sender
print "preparing to send message..."

SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587

send_from = 'myemail@gmail.com'
password = 'PASSWORD'
subject = ''  
print "Sending: ", body
recipient = sender
print "Send to: ", recipient
headers = ["From: " + send_from,
       "Subject: " + subject,
       "To: " + recipient,
       "MIME-Version: 1.0",
       "Content-Type: text/plain"]
       #"Content-Type: text/html"]
        #to send html
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(send_from, password)

session.sendmail(send_from, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

As you can see, it uses credentials to send an email from a gmail account. I added a comment in to show you how to send html in the email. Let me know if you need any more help.

Using php and Pear mail package:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<from.gmail.com>';
$to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

Or, if you would just like to run the python script from php, you could do something like this:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: this is fantastic. one more question related to fact im python novice - what is the file type it goes into say if i want to trigger it from php script?

Comment: I added a php example that you can use.

Comment: fantastic, thanks baba, uv been more than a big help. I will try this out and get back to you, it may b a few days so will mark as done.

Comment: Anytime! I'll keep an eye out